# Java 1.5 Filter JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to filter some rows in a JTable but all the stuff google found me is for java 1.6. I would like to do this using java 1.5 since i can not upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) library to accomplish this:

e.g.

```
Filter[] filterArray = { new PatternFilter("(.*1st.*)|(.*Final.*)", 0, 0) };
FilterPipeline filters = new FilterPipeline(filterArray);
table.setFilters(filters);
```

There's an article here on this:

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18819.html

You can chain various filters together using the FilterPipeline and there's a bunch of built in filters that can be used (ShufflerSorter, PatternFilter).

It should provide you with what you need without resorting to a Java 6 upgrade.

Comment: Word of warning - The performance over large datasets is pretty poor in comparison to JDK 6's JTable filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them (I'm lucky enough to be using 1.6) but you could try [Glazed Lists](http://www.publicobject.com/glazedlists/). It seems to work with 1.5.